# AspectJ how to catch a NoResultException and return null instead

Tags: java, exception, aspectj, aspect

I want to use AspectJ to catch a `NoResultException` and return null instead.
(Obviously I'm an Aspect noob)

Here's the method that does the querying:

```
@Override
public Company getCompanyBySomeNumber(String someNumber) {
    TypedQuery<Company> query = em.createQuery("select c from Company c where c.someNo = ?1", Company.class);
    query.setParameter(1, someNumber);
    return query.getSingleResult();
```

I have several hundred of these calls and I don't want to litter each and every one with a `try/catch` to change the `NoResultException` into a null result.

So I want to write an aspect to catch the exception and change the result to `null`.

Here's the aspect code (please note I'm using annotations).
Something like this:

```
@Aspect 
public class NullifyNoResultException {

    @Pointcut("execution(my.namespace.where.the.queries.are * *Throwable(..))")
    void throwableMethod() {}

    @Around("throwableMethod()")
    public void swallowThrowing(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        try {
            pjp.proceed();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
           //TODO change the return value to null
```

**How do I change the return value to null**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change your method to:

```
@Around("throwableMethod()")
public Object swallowThrowing(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    try {
        return pjp.proceed();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        return null;
    }
}
```